# Multiple concurrent connections in node to mssql

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node with express and mssql and querying the database works fine.  However, if I pass 2 concurrent requests at exactly the same time, I get:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Database is already connected! Call close before connecting to different database.

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');



    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
        database: 'db123',
        server: 'server1',
        driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
        options: {
            trustedConnection: true
        },
    })

    var conn = pool;


var server = app.listen(5001, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});



// GET: SQL Stored procedure return time codes
app.get('/codes/:userid/:showclosed', function (req, res) {
    conn.connect().then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        request.input('userid', req.params.userid);
        request.input('showclosed', parseInt(req.params.showclosed));
        request.execute('sel_new', function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordsets)); // Result in JSON format
            conn.close();
        })
    })
    })
```

EDIT:

Here is what I ended up with:

```
app.get('/codes/:userid/:showclosed', function (req, res) {
    //const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
   (async function () {
    try {
        let pool = await conn;
        // Stored procedure       
        let result2 = await pool.request()
            .input('userid', req.params.userid)
            .input('showclosed', parseInt(req.params.showclosed))
            .execute('StoredProcedure1', function(err, recordsets, returnValue, affected) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                res.end(JSON.stringify(recordsets)); // Result in JSON format
                //sql.close();
            })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})()

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
})
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using `conn.connect()` on every request, this initialises the connection pool and should be used when your service starts up.

So you want `conn.connect()` to happen straight after `var conn = pool`. This will instruct the connection pool to open a connection to the database which your application can then use on-demand in your various endpoints. You can see an example of this in the [mssql library documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#quick-example). The code opens a connection with `sql.connect()` and then goes on to use the `sql` object to create and execute SQL queries. In your example you'd use `conn` rather than `sql`. I've not used the library myself but that's what the documentation seems to suggest.

You also shouldn't close the connection after making a call into the database, as you might have no guessed this will close the entire pool of connections. The idea is to open a pool of connections and leave them around for as long as the service is running, you should definetely run `conn.close()` during the shutdown phase though.

Comment: Thanks this helped.  I'm gonna comment on my original question with my solution.

Comment: @Dylan if this was the answer you needed, could you accept it for people searching for the same issue in the future. Otherwise, you should post your solution as an answer yourself and make it as correct :)

Comment: Hi @ElliotBlackburn, what if I have a web server that should always runr? Do you have any suggestion when to close the pool? Thanks.

Comment: @nypogi, close the pool when the server is terminated for whatever reason. That could be it shuts down ready for you to deploy a new version, or if it falls over due to unhandled exceptions. Remember to always have the max connections on your DB set to higher than your server uses, otherwise a server that locks up badly or fails to disconnect, could still hold up all your DB connections.

Comment: @Dylan could you accept this answer by pressing the tick? It sounds like this solved your problem, and some other peoples as well.